# How to edit textfield (EditText) in GridView? for Sudoku solving app

Tags: android, gridview, android-edittext, adapter, sudoku

I'm making a Sudoku solver app. I want to make an activity on which a user can enter the initial values of the Sudoku... and I don't wanna have to go into the XML and add 81 separate EditText tags.

I thought it would be smarter to use a GridView + BaseAdapter combo! Sooo...

Currently I have a Cell class representing a Sudoku cell, and as suggested, a GridView + CellAdapter implementation. The layout of a grid item includes just one EditText (no text set). This gives me the result of a clean 9x9 grid of EditText on the activity.

**PROBLEM: the EditTexts are uneditable.**

You can type numbers into them, but once you dismiss the keyboard, the text goes back to being blank. What is going on here? Does it have to do with the Adapter?

**Code:**

```
public class CellAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity context;
    private Cell[] cells;

    public CellAdapter(Activity c, Cell[] s) {
        context = c;
        cells = s;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cells.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return cells[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        //Cell cell = cells[i];

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        View gridViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.square_layout, null, true);

        return gridViewItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend to use TextView and custom keyboard to display only from 0-9. When you click on a TextView, highlight that field to indicate current selection

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!!

I changed my getView method to this:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Cell c = cells[i];
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.square_layout, null);
            holder.et = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_value);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        EditText et;
    }
```

the key is to not do edittext.setText() because that makes the field keep the same value